# How do I write elements of a list into mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, arraylist, mariadb, iot

I have a python list of about 200 values being generated every 5 seconds that need to be stored in a database with the timestamp. Because of the time factor, I think it is better stored in a column but I have not been able to figure out how. I can't pass the list variable directly into the database because MySQL does not support it. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: The most simple way is to convert your list into some scalar value (CSV string or JSON array/object) and store it. The correctness if this option depends on the further operations with this data - if they are retrieved as-is then this is useful.

Comment: @Akina This is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## MySQL

I will start assuming you have nothing set up. Just follow from whatever step you are currently on.

First, you will have to [install mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Next log in and create a user account:

```sql
& sudo mysql
mysql> CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> exit
```

Then you need to install python package `mysql`

```sh
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
```

In your script, connect to mysql:

```py
import mysql.connector

try:
    with mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='username',
        password='password'
    ) as connection:
        print(connection)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The next step is to create database and table:

```sql
$ sudo mysql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
mysql> USE mydatabase;
mysql> CREATE TABLE vals(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    value FLOAT,
    date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
mysql> DESCIRBE vals;
exit
```

Finally, you can add your values to database, using python script:

```py
import mysql.connector
import random

def save(values):
    try:
        with mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='username',
            password='password',
            database="mydatabase"
        ) as connection:
            sql = "INSERT INTO vals (value) VALUES (%s)"
            mycursor = connection.cursor()
            for v in values:            
                mycursor.execute(sql, (v,))
            connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vals = [random.random() * 100 for _ in range(1000)]
    save(vals)
```

After some tests, the average time to save one item is around 0.157936 ms, so saving 200 values wouldn't be noticeable (31ms)

## JSON, CSV

As @Akina mentions in a comment, you can as well save the data into a `.json` or `.csv` file. These methods are significantly faster, but saving data into a database rather than loose files is more reliable.

```py
import json
import random
import datetime

vals = [[random.random() * 100, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")] for _ in range(200)]
with open('vals.json', 'a+') as f:
    json.dump(vals, f)
```

Average time per item: 0.0067961ms
Time per all batch 200 values: 1.35ms

```py
import csv
import random
import datetime

vals = [random.random() * 100 for _ in range(200)]
with open('vals.csv', 'a+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for v in vals:
        writer.writerow([v, datetime.datetime.now()])
```

Average time per item: 0.00701427ms
Time per all batch 200 values: 1.41ms

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response Mat. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, import time and mysql libraries. Generate your list and put
   it in an array.
2. There after, use a for each statement to push every listed item to
   mysql table.
3. You will invoke sql INSERT INTO function and define db destination
   and authentication within the python script.

Comment: My Pleasure Juwonlo. Good Luck!